# Ruby gsub not adhering to named group when replacing with regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to split a string by commas that do not occur within a quoted substring. My approach is to

- Replace the commas within quoted substrings with some special token,
- Split the string by commas, then
- Replace the occurrences of the token with a comma (in the split up strings).

I realize that there's probably a simpler way of doing this, but now I'm just interested in why the named group replacement isn't working as I describe below.

I have a regex that identifies commas within quoted substrings as a named capture `commahere`:

```
COMMA_INSIDE_QUOTES_REGEX = /
  (?<quote>[\"\'])      # start by finding either single or double quote
  (?<postquote>.*?)     # then lazy capture any other chars until...
  (?<commahere>\,)      # ...we find the comma
  (?<postcomma>.*?)     # then lazy capture any other chars until...
  (\k<quote>)           # ...we find the matching single or double quote
/x
```

In the following test string, the regexp matches `de,f` and in `jk,a,l` but not the others, as I expect.

```
str = 'abc,"de,f",ghi,"jk,a,l"'
COMMA_INSIDE_QUOTES_REGEX.match(str)
#=> #<MatchData "\"de,f\"" quote:"\"" postquote:"de" commahere:"," postcomma:"f">
```

But when I use `gsub` to replace the named captures with a special token, the entire match is replaced, not the  named group (plus two more commas!):

```
COMMA_TOKEN = '<--COMMA-->'
str.gsub(COMMA_INSIDE_QUOTES_REGEX,"\\k<commahere>#{COMMA_TOKEN}")
#=> "abc,,<--COMMA-->,ghi,,<--COMMA-->"
```

Comment: CSV is a surprisingly unpleasant format to work with. Save yourself from needless pain and suffering by using the CSV parser in the standard library.

Comment: Agreed.  Don't reinvent the wheel, CSV parsing is a solved and finished task.  Use what is already proven to work.

Comment: @muistooshort How do you know its CSV? It may be, or it may not.

Comment: @sawa: What else do you call a list of values separated by commas? Just because it doesn't come from a file on disk with a `.csv` extension doesn't mean that it isn't CSV data.

Comment: If you do want to roll your own here, you may find that stringscanner is easier to worth with for this sort of task

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding something.

```
str.gsub(COMMA_INSIDE_QUOTES_REGEX,"\\k<commahere>#{COMMA_TOKEN}")
```

means:

1. Try to match the regex `COMMA_INSIDE_QUOTES_REGEX` within the string `str`.
2. If successful, replace *that entire match* by a string built from the contents of `<commahere>` and the contents of `COMMA_TOKEN`.

It does not mean "replace only the group `<commahere>` with whatever follows it. Your approach is wrong, and what you're trying to do can't be done the way you're trying to do it. You should indeed take mu's advice and use a CSV parser.

If you're interested in what a regex would look like that could actually work, it would have to be built like this:

1. Match a comma.
2. Check that this comma is inside a string. This can be done by counting the number of quotes following the comma. If that number is odd, the comma is inside a string.
3. The previous trick works even if quotes are embedded in the string itself because these quotes are escaped by doubling.

So, this is your regex:

```
result = str.gsub(
    /,        # Match a comma
    (?!       # only if it's not followed by
     (?:      # the following group:
      [^"]*"  #  any number of non-quote characters and a quote
      [^"]*"  #  twice (so exactly two quotes are matched)
     )*       # any number of times (including 0)
     [^"]*    # followed (if at all) by only non-quote characters
     \Z       # until the end of the string.
    )         # End of lookahead
    /x, '<--COMMA-->')
```

Comment: Thanks all.  You're right.  I did misunderstand the Ruby documentation on gsub:  If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form \\d, where d is a group number, or \\k<n>, where n is a group name.  I parsed that to mean that the capture groups could be used as targets for the replacement.  And, the CSV tip caused me to do a palm-to-forehead smack.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That is how `gsub` works. `gsub` replaces the entire match with the replacement string. Otherwise, how would `gsub` know which substring of the entire match you want to replace? Where is that information?

In order to exclude a substring from being included in the replaced part, you have to use lookback, negative lookback, lookahead, or negative lookahead, depending on your need. However, lookbacks do not allow strings with a variable length, so you you can use lookbacks or lookaheads for `quote` and `postcomma`, but have to reproduce the `postquote` part in the replacement string.

There are several other things that are wrong with your regexp. Constant substrings like `"`, `,` are easily referred to as is. It does not make sense to capture them with names like `quote` or `commahere`. Also, it looks like you do not know how to construct the replacement string in a regexp. You shouldn't have `\k<commahere>` in the replacement string if you want to replace that with something else.

Comment: Thanks sawa.  My capturing of the constant substrings was only done to help myself keep track of what the regexp was doing.  It makes a ton of difference during debugging, at least to me.  Think of it as inline documentation to be removed once everything was working, or not.